# PHP invert array numbers

Tags: php, arrays

It's a simple question, but searching here I found different variations, but not really what I need. So:

Say I have array of numbers: [1,4,5,7,9]
What I need is an inverted result set of numbers up to max 10: [2,3,6,8,10]

Comment: What do you mean by "inverted"? Why is `1->2` but `4->3`?

Comment: I failed to notice the pattern between your input and desired output.

Comment: It's just changing from one set of numbers less than 10 to another set that is different from the first.. I can't even imagine what this could apply to.

Comment: @Tar I have 20 checkboxes with values from 1 to 20. When you uncheck it, a row has to be deleted from the database, and checkbox values are also ID's in a table. And if checkbox isn't checked, the value isn't set in an array (name=checkbox[]). So I'd just delete records with "inverted" values from checked ones. That's what I came up with, maybe thare is a more elegant way...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$initialArray = array(1,4,5,7,9);
$requiredRange = range(1,10);

$invertedArray = array_diff($requiredRange,$initialArray);
```